# iterate dictionary when having list as values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import sympify

class myclass():

    def __init__(self, expression ='', values = {}):
        self.expression = expression
        self.values = values


    def execute(self):

        expr = sympify(self.expression)

        for v in self.values:
            expr = expr.subs(str(v),self.values[v])

        self.result = expr.evalf()

        return  self.result
```

Which executes an expression when having a dictionary as input.

With this data:

```
values = {'c':1, 'd':2}
print(myclass('c + d',values).execute())
```

I am receiving : 3 which is correct.

Now, is there a way when I have this data:

```
values = {'c':[1,2], 'd':[3,4]}
```

to call `execute` and obtain the result?Note, that I don't want to alter the `execute` fuction in order to check if I have a list and then add a loop.

I just want to iterate through dict, something like:

```
for k, v in thevalues.items():
    for i in v:
        print(myclass('c + d',.......).execute())
```

Comment: I think perhaps you want to turn it into a list of dicts like `[{'c': 1, 'd': 3}, {'c': 2, 'd': 4}]`? What about `map(dict, (zip(values.keys(), v) for v in zip(*values.values())))` to give you the list, which you then iterate over and pass each value to your class + execute function.

Comment: @PaulRooney:Thanks, fir the idea ,this works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution may be:

```
# assuming the length of the list for 'c' and 'd' is the same. calaculate the length of the list for 'c' or 'd'

for k, v in values.items():
    length_of_values_list = len(v)
    break

for i in range(length_of_values_list):
       print [myclass('c+d', dict([(k,v[i]) for k, v in values.items()])).execute()]
```

results in

```
[4.000]
[6.000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a nested list inside the dictionary. `values['c'][0]` will evaluate to 1, and `values['c'][1]` will evaluate to 2.

So you can have:

```
for k, v in thevalues.items():
    for i in thevalues[k]:
        print(myclass('c + d',.......).execute())
```